# Carrying Entity Framework Core context through to Data layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I scaffolded an existing database into a data layer project using the command

```
Scaffold-DbContext Command
```

I also have an ASP.NET MVC project.

In the `ConfigureServices` method of my `Startup.cs`, I have

```
services.AddDbContext<GlassesMVDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddScoped<GlassesMVDataContext>();
```

I have a connection string in my `appsetting.json`.

My datacontext has a constructor

```
public GlassesMVDataContext(DbContextOptions<GlassesMVDataContext> options)
        : base(options)
{
}
```

In the data layer I want to be able to do something like this:

```
using (var context = new GlassesMVDataContext())
{
}
```

I want to be able to use the connection string and have the context understand that in the data layer.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You already made available the DbContext to the Dependency Injection (DI) system when you called "services.AddDbContext(options => ...)", so that, the connection string is already set, so let's go with this approach.

In this example, I am assuming the DbContext will be used in a service resolved from DI in the service's constructor:

```
public interface IMyDataService
{
   void DoSomething();
}

public class MyDataService: IMyDataService
{
   private GlassesMVDataContext  _context;

   public MyDataService(GlassesMVDataContext context)
   {
      // The connection string is already set in Startup.cs
      _context = context;
   }

   public void DoSomething()
   {
      // Do something with _context here....
   }
}
```